# Freemarker/Topdesk conditional content

Tags: freemarker

I am trying to alter a step in one of our automated actions with freemarker, as the error is caused by a null value, which may be expected.

The execution log in Topdesk shows the following:

**Error while processing FreeMarker template: The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> _responses.get_ticket_info.body.object**  [in template "action" at line 1, column 82]

[...]
Tip: *If the failing expression is known to legally refer to something that's sometimes null or missing,* either specify a default value like myOptionalVar!myDefault, or use **<#if myOptionalVar??>when-present<#else>when-missing</#if>**. (These only cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole expression, use parenthesis: (myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionalVar.foo)??

The full URL is as follows:
**${_variables.topdesk_url?no_esc}/tas/api/assetmgmt/assets?$filter=name%20eq%20'${_responses.get_ticket_info.body.object.name}'**

I am not sure about the proper syntax/values...

As my conditional I currently have
**<#if ${_variables.topdesk_url?no_esc}/tas/api/assetmgmt/assets?$filter=name%20eq%20'${_responses.get_ticket_info.body.object.name}'??>true<#else>false</#if>**

although I guess, since it's saying the first one only covers the last part of the expression, I only need to put **<#if ${_responses.get_ticket_info.body.object.name}??>true<#else>false</#if>**

I have not created a variable in the first step. the first step's result (_responses.get_ticket_info.body) contains a the variable **object**, which has a variable **name** which in this case has the value "null".

So I would like to skip step 2, and consequently every following step, instead of step 2 causing an error and every following step being skipped.

Can you please help remove my doubt?

Comment: `<#if ${` is merely a syntax error, and the template won't even start with that. You must not use `${...}` at places where FreeMarker already expects a FreeMarker expression.

Comment: Also you state that you need to handle the case when `name` is `null`, but the error message at the top says that `object` is already `null`. Also, could you clarify, what exactly do you want in the output when there's a `null`? Because if you just want to show a default/placeholder value, you don't even need an `#if`.

Comment: This is a step in a process.
What I'm trying to do is prevent the error.
In the previous step of the process the ticket information is collected, and in this step the object of the ticket is singled out.
Since this ticket is a voicemail message, there is no "object" for it, so its value is "null".
What I would like is to gracefully handle the "null" value if it occurs, with perhaps a message, or a dummy value instead of this error.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `<#if _responses.get_ticket_info.body.object??>`, as the error message suggests too.